# Align content to the bottom (Navbar)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Well I would like to align the content of the list to the bottom so they would align with eachother in a neatly way or if you guys got a other way to do it I would appreciate that to.

```css
.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}

ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}


ul.topnav li {
    float: right;
}


ul.topnav li a {
    padding-top: 39px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}


ul.topnav li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}


ul.topnav li.icon {
    display: none;
}



@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
    }
    ul.topnav li.icon {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    ul.topnav.responsive {
        position: relative;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <header>
        <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <li class="pull-left"><a><h1>Logo-Text</h1></a></li>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="find">Find us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li class="icon">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}

ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
  text-align: right;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}


ul.topnav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}


ul.topnav li a {
    padding-top: 39px;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1;
}

ul.topnav li a h1{
  margin: 0;
}


ul.topnav li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}


ul.topnav li.icon {
    display: none;
}



@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
    }
    ul.topnav li.icon {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    ul.topnav.responsive {
        position: relative;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <header>
        <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="find">Find us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li class="icon">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
            </li>
          <li><a><h1>Logo-Text</h1></a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</div>
```

I just remove floating from `li`. `ul` will be `text-align: right;` then

`li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}`

It will make your list item bottom align. Hope this help.